# Defining a relation as a simply set of pairs (without underlaying sets) is wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If I define a binary relation $r$ simply like a set of pairs, in formal way:

$\forall u ( u\in r \rightarrow \exists x\exists y\ u=(x,y))$

Is it possible to prove that the class $dom(r)=\{x|\exists y\ (x,y)\in r\}$ is a set?

I think that is a wrong definition and the right formal definition is:

$\exists a \exists b \forall u ( u\in r \rightarrow \exists x \in a \exists y \in b \land \ u=(x,y))$

Comment: You can define the cartesian product of two *sets* $A \times B$ and you can prove that it is a set: if $z= (x,y)$ and $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then $z \in \mathcal P (\mathcal P(A \cup B))$.

Comment: Having proved that $A \times B$ is a set, we have that $R \subseteq A \times B$ is a set.

Comment: This is ok for second definiton but in first definition we don't have that A and B exist. So I think the first way is a wrong way beacuse we maybe cannot define A and B like sets. (If I'm not wrong)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. In my experience, a relation is something you define on a set, hence the ordered pairs definition tells you who is related to whom. It seems to me that your $x$ and $y$ have to come from somewhere.

Comment: The second definition is the usual I want to see if from the first definition is possible to proof that dom(r) is a set in such way the second would be equivlent to first

Comment: @asv As my answer shows, the answer is yes. However, it's worth noting that I use the axiom (scheme) of Replacement. In [the weaker set theory Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) (or its relatives), which is ZF without Replacement, this proof *fails*, and indeed I suspect the claim is false in general; so in such a weak set theory, we usually *do* want a stronger definition of "set relation," such as yours.

Comment: That said, Z and its relatives are very weird beasts indeed, and outside of very very special contexts one rarely works with them. So the answer to your question is yes *in all but some very strange contexts*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask (paraphrased):

> If we say $r$ is a binary relation whenever $\forall u ( u\in r \rightarrow \exists x\exists y\ u=(x,y))$, is it possible to prove that the class $dom(r)=\{x|\exists y\ (x,y)\in r\}$ is a set?

The answer is: yes, **if by "binary relation" we mean "*set* binary relation."** There are two kinds of relations: set relations, which are sets of ordered pairs, and class relations, which are classes of ordered pairs. A class relation need not have a set as its domain: e.g. the relation "$x=x$" is a class relation with domain all of $V$.

On the other hand, suppose $r$ is a set of ordered pairs. Then **we can indeed prove that its domain is a set**. One way to do this is the following:

- Let $\varphi(x, y)$ be the formula "$y$ is the left coordinate of $x$" - that is, "$\exists z(x=(y, z))$."
- For each $a\in r$ there is exactly one $b$ satisfying $\varphi(a, b)$; so we may apply [Replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) to get $\{b: \exists a\in r(\varphi(a, b))\}$.
- But this set is exactly $dom(r)$!

Comment: That's fine. Only one thing: $\{b: \exists a\in r(\varphi(a, b))\}$ shouldn't be $\{b: \exists a\in r \  \varphi(a, b)\}$?

Comment: @asv That's up to how you want to organize your parentheses; I like mine the way I wrote them, but different people use different conventions.

Comment: Ok I had misunderstood the parentheses, I was thinking r applied to $\varphi(a,b)$ (and it doesn't sense, now I see). Sorry, my mistake :)

Comment: @asv Oh, I see! That's a really good point, actually: I'm not used to more parentheses generating more confusion, but you're right that they do here. Another option, really the most clear but also cumbersome, is: $$\{b: \exists a(a\in r\mbox{ and }\varphi(a, b))\}.$$ (Replace "and" with "$\wedge$" if [you've seen that symbol before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Notation).)

Comment: Ok, that's better than mine.